# LoadLibrary of a file with other the 'dll' extension

Tags: windows, dll, loadlibrary

Is it possible to load a dll file that doesn't have a 'dll' extension?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, just provide full file name, including extension (or without extension, if file name doesn't contain it).

Answer (score 1):

yes, it is possible, but the file should still conform to the "dll" format (it should conform to the PE format).

Comment: What is PE format ?

Comment: Portable Executable file format: the format used on Windows to organize and store executable programs, dlls,object codes, etc. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Executable

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but you need to append a dot (`.`) to the end of the path so that Windows doesn't automatically append the `.dll` extension:

> If the string specifies a module name without a path and the file name extension is omitted, the function appends the default library extension .dll to the module name. To prevent the function from appending .dll to the module name, include a trailing point character (.) in the module name string.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684175.aspx